# MYSQL if statement (From mysql newb)

Tags: sql, mysql

Is it possible to get this if statement to NOT print a column if EQ_Type!='ENGINE'?
The empty column on my out put is bothering me.

```
select if(EQUIPMENT.EQ_Type='ENGINE',ENGINE.Capacity,'') as Capacity, ....
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't selectively include a column on a row by row basis.

Answer (score 1):

No - you will have to either have a column for all rows, or omit the comun altogether. You can control exactly what is displayed by using `CASE`, which is basically the same as you have done using `IF` (maybe a tad more self-explanatory):

```
select case when equipment.eq_type = 'ENGINE' then
   engine.capacity
else
   'put something you want here'
end as capacity
from...
```